# How to add background image in paint class in Android?

Tags: android

I am working on android. I want add background image to paint class but there is no setBackground() in paint class. How to add background image by using paint class?

Answer (score 0):

`Paint` is not `View` and don't have background field. As documentation says:

> Paint class holds the style and color information about how to draw geometries, text and bitmaps.